# Binding the Json data to kendo grid/chart

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Below is the Json data that I get from my API. I am trying to build a kendo chart from this. Is there a good approach to access the values(350,90) and bind to the chart.

```
    "Issues": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Rya"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "RH"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "350"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Mike"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "ML"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Code so far, but I'm trying to make it dynamic

```
this.chartTitle = data.Name;
this.doughnutChartLabels[0] = data.Data.Issues[0].Values[0].Value;
this.doughnutChartLabels[1] = data.Data.Issues[1].Values[0].Value;
this.doughnutChartData[0] = data.Data.Issues[0].Values[2].Value;
this.doughnutChartData[1] = data.Data.Issues[1].Values[2].Value;
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: At present I tried this. But I am trying to make it dynamic.     this.chartTitle = data.Name;
    this.doughnutChartLabels[0] = data.Data.Issues[0].Values[0].Value;
   this.doughnutChartLabels[1] = data.Data.Issues[1].Values[0].Value;
     this.doughnutChartData[0] = data.Data.Issues[0].Values[2].Value;
     this.doughnutChartData[1] = data.Data.Issues[1].Values[2].Value;

Comment: Please edit your question and add your source code there.